# Has anyone a setup of Hudson CI server combined with the symbol server (symsrv.dll)?

Tags: debugging, hudson, symbols

We have Hudson CI server which uses msbuild to build our C# code. Does anyone who uses Hudson CI server also has the symbol server (symsrv.dll) configured?

I would like to understand what is the best way of combining the two.

Thanks.

P.S.

Apparently, ServerFault is not the right place for this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/101726/has-anyone-a-setup-of-hudson-ci-server-combined-with-the-symbol-server-symsrv-dl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using both Hudson and a symbol server,but the two aren't really that connected. It's the build script's responsibility to store the symbols in the server. The only relation Hudson has to this process is passing a parameter that signals the build script that symbols should be stored (we don't want to store the symbols anytime a developer runs the script on his machine)

Comment: Thanks On Freund. I understand that. Can you describe the logic you employ to decide when the build is qualified for the symbol server?

Comment: Basically every Hudson build is qualified, so all it takes is a boolean parameter that defaults to false in the build script and Hudson sets it to true.

Comment: That's what I think to do. BTW, do you let the build products be Hudson built artefacts and then let the symbol server reference them or do you actually copy the files to the symbol store?

Comment: The build eventually produces some files that are artifacts, but I don't see a reason to set the PDB files as artifacts.